# Beans in Difference Packages giving error 'No Qualifying Bean of type available'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Project Details: One repository package containing (src/main/java -> com.pluralSight.Repository)

```
@Component
public interface FlightRepository extends CrudRepository<Flight, Long>
```

One Entity package containing (src/main/java -> com.pluralSight.Entity)

```
@Entity
public class Flight
```

I am testing repository 'Save' by test case written in springDataApplicationTests.java underneath (src/test/java -> com.pluralSight.SpringData)

```
@Component
@DataJpaTest
class SpringDataApplicationTests {
    
    @Autowired
    FlightRepository repository;

    @Test
    void testCrudRepository() {
        
        Flight f = new Flight();
        f.setArrivedFrom("America");
        f.setDeparturedTo("Dubai");
        
        repository.save(f);
        
        Assertions.assertThat(repository.findAll()).hasSize(1);
        
    }

}
```

I created two appConfig.java (trying hit and trial solutions).first Underneath src/main/java and second underneath src/test/java

```
 @ComponentScan("com.pluralSight.Repository")
     @Configuration
     public class appConfig {
     }
```

But when i run the test, getting error

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.pluralSight.Repository.FlightRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations:

Comment: Ditch those config classes. Make sure your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class is in the `com.pluralSight` package and not in a sub-package.

Comment: M. deinum man this worked. SpringBootApplication was inside sub-package. I moved it out into com.pluralsight @M.Deinum